# How to make spaces in URI readable by SPARQL queries in R?

Tags: r, encoding, sparql, space

As we write SPARQL in Virtuoso, it is easy to escape a space within an URI by coding the space with `%20`. However, when I install the package SPARQL in R, the escape fails. There is an argument `curl_args` in command SPARQL, which should work around this issue. But it is not successful. Here is my R scripts:

```
###Step 1: Building up the query

query <-"select ?instance {
?form a <URI name> .
?instance a <http://StemAddress/Where My Question Is> .
}"
###Step 2: Executing the query
qd <- SPARQL(endpoint,queryC,curl_args = curlPercentEncode("http://StemAddress/Where My Question Is", amp = TRUE, codes = " ", post.amp = TRUE))


####In Step 1, what it works in Virtuoso is
select ?instance {
?form a <URI name> .
?instance a <http://StemAddress/Where%20My%20Question%20Is> .
}

####But this just threw me an error in R environment.
```

Comment: What error is thrown? And did you check how R encoded the query String?

Comment: I tried + which wasn't recognized either and the error message is "there are illegal characters".

Answer (score 0):

Writing `%20` is not an escape for a space. It really is the three characters `%-2-0` in the URI.  Encode != escape.  Spaces in URIs are illegal.

Comment: I replaced %20 with %-2-0, and the error message "Illegal characters found in URL" disappeared, but the query result became empty. I am sure there are data there.

Comment: 3 characters "%20"  (I was stressing the separate characters with "%-2-0"